# What is the probability for $x$ to be positive only?

Tags: probability, analytic-geometry, quadratics

If $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$ and $x+y+z=5,\, xy+yz+zx=3$, what is the probability that $x>0$ ? $$(a)\quad\frac3{16}\qquad (b)\quad\frac5{16}\qquad (c)\quad\frac{13}{16}\qquad (d)\quad \frac{15}{16}$$

I've tried forming a cubic equation and then trying to analyze its roots.

How to approach these type of questions?

Comment: Kindly show your work .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: There has to be a probability distribution on the reals, for this question to make sense, no?

Comment: Hello! First idea is consider these bodies $V = \{x + y + z = 5\}$ and $W = \{xy+ xz + yz = 3\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and find part with $Q = \{x > 0\}$. Then quotient of volume of  $Q$ and volume of $W \cap V$ is the result.

Comment: The cubic polynomial formed with roots $x,y,z$ can't have two negative roots because the derivative vanishes at positive numbers of the domain. Does anyone agree with me on this? So, the probability for just one root to be positive is zero.

Comment: @ SarGe i have found the cubic equation t^3-(x+y+z)t^2+(xy+yz+zx)t -(xyz ) using the above equations as t^3-5t^2+3t-(5/3)^3

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Yes sir i will take care of that in the next post.

Comment: In light of the answers posted so far, this seems to be a badly flawed problem. Where did you find it?

Comment: @ David K I found out this question while giving mock test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $x+y+z=5$ and $xy+yz+zx=3$, we find that $x^2+y^2+z^2=(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx)=19$.

Now we find the range of $x$. For this, we write $y+z=5-x$ and $y^2+z^2=19-x^2$.

Now by a basic application of [A.M-G.M Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), or [Titu's Lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/), we can write $y^2+z^2 \geq \dfrac{(y+z)^2}{2} \implies 19-x^2 \geq \frac{(5-x)^2}{2} \iff (x+1)\left(x-\frac{13}{3}\right)\leq 0$.

Therefore $x \in \left[-1,\frac{13}{3}\right]$, thus the probability that $x>0$ is $\dfrac{\frac{13}{3}}{1+\frac{13}{3}}=\boxed{\frac{13}{16}}$.

Comment: This makes little sense to me. First, the inequality is just a bound, it says that $x$ must be in that range but it does not need to be "tight" (I mean, one could write $x \in \left[-10,10\right]$, and that's  also true). Second, the jump to "probability"  is unjustified (why would you assume that the distribution is uniform in that range?). Third, the question asks for $x$ being "positive only" which (I guess, it's a little confusing) means that $y$ and $z$ must be negative, you are ignoring that.

Comment: @leonbloy How can $x\in [-10,10]$? when i showed that $x$ lies in that particular range? If it went out of that range, $y,z$ will not remain real. Second, it is symmetric in $x,y,z$, so distribution should be uniform in that interval. Third, what I concluded from "positive only" means that simply $x>0$. Otherwise, O.P should have written it clearly that $y$ and $z$ are negative. Fourth, my answer matches an answer given in the options.

Comment: Logically, $x\in[-1,13/3] \implies x\in[-10,10].$ The previous comment seems to be reacting to what you *wrote* as opposed to what you *wanted* to write. What I think you wanted to write was, "$x$ takes on every value in $[-1,13/3]$," or perhaps, "$-1<x<13/3$ and the bounds are tight." Sometimes you need more words.

Comment: If we are going to make assumptions about the joint distribution of $x,y,z,$ I think the most reasonable assumption is that it is uniform on the circle found in Robert Israel's answer, and that none of the multiple-choice answers is correct. Sure, we **could** assume $x$ is uniform, but then $y$ and $z$ could not also be uniform, and how do we justify giving such different treatment to $x$? But at least this answer shows what might have been going through someone's mind when they created the problem and set the multiple-choice answer values.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions of your two equations form a circle in $xyz$ space, the intersection of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 19$ with the plane $x+y+z=5$, which can be parametrized as
$$ \eqalign{x &= \frac{5}{3} - \frac{8}{3} \cos(t)\cr
            y &= \frac{5}{3} + \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} \sin(t) + \frac{4}{3} \cos(t)\cr
            z &= \frac{5}{3} - \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} \sin(t) + \frac{4}{3} \cos(t)\cr} $$

It's not at all clear how to interpret "probability" in this context,  but there is no $t$ for which $x > 0$ while $y \le 0$ and $z \le 0$.  So if $x > 0$ **only** means $x > 0$ while $y \le 0$ and $z \le 0$, the answer must be $0$. On the other hand, if you asked for the probability that $x > 0$, one possible interpretation would be the probability that $x>0$ if you took a random $t$ uniformly from $[-\pi,\pi]$.
Then you'd get $x > 0$ iff $\cos(t) < 5/8$, i.e. with probability $1 - \frac{\arccos(5/8)}{\pi} \approx 0.7149010415$.  This is an irrational number. So again "none of the above".

Comment: what do you think of my solution?

Comment: I agree with David K's objections in his comments.